# How to remove all tags and get the pure text?

Tags: asp.net, html, regex, html-agility-pack, informix

I had to store the user input text in my database with `HTML and CSS` formats.

The case is:

[RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) ,The user copy the text from MSWord to this editor then i store this text in the database with that format . then when retrieve the data in the report or some label some tags appear wrapping the text !!

I use regular expression to remove all the formats but in vain it succeeds sometimes and not all the time .

```
private static Regex oClearHtmlScript = new Regex(@"<(.|\n)*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public static string RemoveAllHTMLTags(string sHtml)
        {

            sHtml = sHtml.Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty);
            sHtml = sHtml.Replace("&gt;", ">");
            sHtml = sHtml.Replace("&lt;", "<");
            sHtml = sHtml.Replace("&amp;", "&");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHtml))
                return string.Empty;

            return oClearHtmlScript.Replace(sHtml, string.Empty);
        }
```

---

I ask How to remove all the format using [HTMLAgility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) or any dependable way to ensure the text is pure  ?

`Note:`The datatype of this field in the database  is [Lvarchar](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/esqlc93.htm)

Comment: Added another suggestion to my answer as the first didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

This should strip out all html tags from a string.

```
sHtml = Regex.Replace(sHtml, "<.*?>", "");
```

Comment: still the same problem for example :

`<span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified`

Comment: It needs to be ***valid HTML tag*** - start with `<` and end with `>`. For example, `<span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified">test</span>` result `test`

Comment: copied from word to editor
`<p style="margin-right: 3.5in; text-align: left; text-indent: 0.5in; line-height: 150%; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><strong><span style="line-height: 150%;">رقم</span></strong></p><p style="margin-right: 3.5in; text-align: left; text-indent: 0.5in; line-height: 150%; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><strong><span style="line-height: 150%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></strong></p><p style="text-align: right; line-height: 150%; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><strong><span style="line-height: 150%;">&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: `</strong></p><p style="text-align: right; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">&nbsp;</span></p><p style="text-align: right; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><strong><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">أحمد</span></strong></p><p style="margin-right: 2.5in; text-align: right; text-indent: 0.5in; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><strong><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">&nbsp; </span></strong><strong> </strong></p>`

Comment: `<p style="text-align: right; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">&nbsp;</span></p><p style="text-align: right; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><strong><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">تحية </span></strong></p><p style="text-align: right; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified Arabic,serif;">نكتب </span>`

Comment: `<strong><span style="font-size: 14pt;" dir="LTR">IBDL Egypt</span></strong></p><p style="text-align: right; direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed;" dir="RTL"><span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified`

The end of text

Comment: Result - `رقم&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;أحمد&nbsp;  &nbsp;تحية نكتب IBDL Egypt<span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified`. Since the original string ends with invalid html tag, you cannot do anything because you have no way of knowing whether html or just pure text.

Comment: hmmmm how to fix this bug :(

Answer (score 3):

HtmlAgility pack makes working with HTML easy.

```
HtmlDocument mainDoc = new HtmlDocument();
string htmlString = "<html><body><h1>Test</h1> more text</body></html>"
mainDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
string cleanText = mainDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1338236.aspx) recommonds the following approach (and seems to have been accepted).

```
Regex.Replace(myHTMLString, @"<p>|</p>|<br>|<br />", "\r\n", );
Regex.Replace(myHTMLString, @"<.+?>", string.Empty);
```

Given you're still having difficulty could you try instantiating a RadEditor and using the .Text property. Ive not used RadEditor before but I did some digging - could you try something like thisL

```
RadEditor editor = new RadEditor();
editor.Content = myHTMLString;
string plainText = editor.Text;
```

This is probably a VERY expensive operation but Id be interested to know if it works!

Comment: still the same problem for example :

`<span style="font-size: 16pt; font-family: Simplified`

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808099/iterate-with-all-elements-and-get-text/10824325#10824325) for how it can be done using the Agility Pack.
You may have to change the code a little to not strip out words less than two characters though. Also, line breaks will be removed as well, so you'll be left with one long line of text.