# Extract data from Web Scraping C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am MVC ASP.NET developer.

I have received the contents from any url, i.e. http, https etc. using WebRequest class.

I have received all the content of that particular url. (for now I took http://google.com)

My next step is to extract buttons, header, footer, colors, text etc.

Here is my code for now:

```
public ActionResult GetContent(UrlModel model) //model having a string URL
which is entered in a text box and method hits using submit button.
{
    //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(model.URL);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(model.URL);

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    ViewBag.Response = responseFromServer;

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    return View();
}
```

Can someone help me with writing the code ?

Also do suggest me with some techniques of data extraction in C#.

Comment: Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303828/how-to-remove-all-tags-and-get-the-pure-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your way to go 
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

There are numerous stackoverflow posts about it. You can easily get any elements from the html.