# string join the innertext of html childnodes

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

My HTML looks like the following

```
<h4>
<span>Cat</span>
<span>Dog</span>
<a href="xxx" class="telcat">Potatoes</a>
</h4>
```

i am trying to produce the following string from the above, which simply the child elements innertext joined by a comma

```
Cat,Dog,Potatoes
```

i tried somthing like

```
 string x = String.Join(",", htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h4").Elements().Select(el => el.InnerText).ToList());
```

however i get looking output, the string i get looks like

```
,Cat,
,Dog,
,Potatoes,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there are TextNodes in the Html that have no text. Fixing that is rather easy though, you just have to filter the empty text.

Like so:

```
 string x = String.Join(",", doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//h4").Elements()
    .Select(el => el.InnerText)
    .Where(text => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)));
```

If you want something like that for the whole page, i posted something similiar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824325/1260405).